# Parse a dynamically named json object in Scala

Tags: scala, spray-json

how can I parse this kind of json with spray-json?
How does the guid object go into a case class or do I need to write some kind of custom reader?

```
{
    "referredEntities":{
        "012e2ec1-c205-4657-81d7-1e06eac1a849":{
            "typeName":"type1",
            "attributes":{
                "owner":"dave",
                "qualifiedName":"test",
                "name":"test"...
```

Comment: It looks like you did not include the entire json object in your question. Please do so, or edit it down to a reasonable size that shows what you need. If this IS the entire JSON string, then your json is bad, and you need to reject it.
That said, the docs for spray-json seem pretty straight-forward, and suggest: `val jsonAst = source.parseJson ` will parse your json.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your JSON object will be something similar to this:

```
{
    "referredEntities": {
        "012e2ec1-c205-4657-81d7-1e06eac1a849":{
            "typeName":"type1",
            "attributes":{
                "owner":"dave",
                "qualifiedName":"test",
                "name":"test"
        }
     },
    "012e2ec1-c205-4657-81d7-1e06ea1234":{
            "typeName":"type2",
            "attributes":{
                "owner":"nicky",
                "qualifiedName":"test1",
                "name":"test22"
        }
     }}
}
```

Consider the following solution:

```
import spray.json._

val source = """{
               |    "referredEntities":{
               |        "012e2ec1-c205-4657-81d7-1e06eac1a849":{
               |            "typeName":"type1",
               |            "attributes":{
               |                "owner":"dave",
               |                "qualifiedName":"test",
               |                "name":"test"
               |        }
               |     },
               |    "012e2ec1-c205-4657-81d7-1e06ea1234":{
               |            "typeName":"type1",
               |            "attributes":{
               |                "owner":"dave",
               |                "qualifiedName":"test",
               |                "name":"test"
               |        }
               |     }}}""".stripMargin

val jsonAst = source.parseJson

case class Attributes(owner: String, qualifiedName: String, name: String)
case class Entity(typeName: String, attributes: Attributes)
case class ReferredEntity(entityUUID: String, entity: Entity)
case class Source(referredEntities: Seq[ReferredEntity])

object MyJsonProtocol extends  DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val attributesFmt = jsonFormat3(Attributes)
  implicit val entityFmt = jsonFormat2(Entity)

  implicit object SourceJsonFormat extends RootJsonReader[Source] {
    def read(value: JsValue) = value.asJsObject.getFields("referredEntities") match {
      case Seq(obj: JsObject) => Source(obj.fields.toSeq.map(item => ReferredEntity(item._1, entityFmt.read(item._2))))
    }
  }
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

SourceJsonFormat.read(jsonAst)
```